# Can page layouts be deleted via an inbound change set?

Tags: change-set

I have several page layouts for the Lead Object.  I have merged them into a new Page Layout Lead-Default.  I want to delete the unused page layouts that I no longer need.  Can this be done in a inbound change set to my production?

Answer (score 3):

Through the change set, you cannot able to delete that.

Either you can manually delete in Production or you can use Eclipse with `destructiveChanges.xml` for deletion.

Refer [Deleting Files from an Organization](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/daas_destructive_changes.htm)

> The package.xml file is a project manifest that lists all the components to retrieve or deploy. Although you can use package.xml to add components, it’s not sufficient to delete them. To delete files, create a delete manifest that’s called destructiveChanges.xml. The format of the delete manifest is the same as package.xml, except that wildcards aren’t supported.

The following sample destructiveChanges.xml file names a single custom object to be deleted:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>MyCustomObject__c</members>
        <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
</Package>
```

Comment: if my ans solves your purpose then accept this so that others may find this useful

Comment: The only caveat with destructive is you cannot use * wild card for members. You have to give the exact layout names in members tag  for deletion.